# Request timeout in Heroku

Tags: java, web-services, heroku

I am lost here with a problem with my app hosted in heroku. First of all details:

The application is a web service listening to http request (post), transforming some data into a soap message to be sent to another web service.

- its a Java app, maven project, y use Jersey to expose my rest service and AXIS2 to create the stub to call to a third party service and send the soap message.

the service works fine, I set up an Apache Tomcat server in my local and works perfectly fine. I push it to heroku and all request time out, all of them. The log gets crazy and it seems that heroku creates several threads and my debug lines appear several times each, so in the end I get an H-12 error BUT sometimes the operation keeps running and even if a get a timeout error I can see that the operation succeeded.

I am lost here, any suggestions how to debug? setup configuration in Heroku? anything?

Thanks a lot !!

EDIT: **After some messages with Heroku here and there they claimed it not being a Heroku problem. However I deployed the same app to CloudBees and is running smoothly there. **

A part of the log: (is huge and I can't paste it all), I can see it is looping forever at some point but I have no idea why this happens in Heroku and not in my local Tomcat.

Java code below this log.

```
2013-08-14T11:10:05.211415+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:25,132 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Entry: AxisOperation::getInputAction
2013-08-14T11:10:05.302301+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:28,554 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Exit: AxisOperation::getInputAction null
2013-08-14T11:10:05.400942+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:28,554 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Entry: AxisOperation::setSoapAction, previous soapAction: null updated soapAction: urn:aDD_Set
2013-08-14T11:10:05.491836+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:28,554 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Exit: AxisOperation::setSoapAction
2013-08-14T11:10:05.590298+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:28,554 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService - mapActionToOperation: Mapping Action to Operation: action: aDD_Set; operation: org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation@63cea096named: {https://wsdlt.mailmanagement.ch}aDD_Set
2013-08-14T11:10:05.686160+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:28,555 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService - DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.callStackToString(JavaUtils.java:564)
2013-08-14T11:10:05.781155+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.mapActionToOperation(AxisService.java:821)
2013-08-14T11:10:05.872017+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.addOperation(AxisService.java:667)
2013-08-14T11:10:05.963805+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.populateAxisService(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:83)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.056816+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:155)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.148557+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:143)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.239199+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:193)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.330053+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.deindeal.utils.Connector2Navision.getStub(Connector2Navision.java:43)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.422462+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.deindeal.servlets.Product_Listener.sendAddProductJson2Nav(Product_Listener.java:55)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.513911+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.604438+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.694775+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.787233+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
2013-08-14T11:10:06.881756+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.019128+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.113107+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.207812+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.299744+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.390147+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.502095+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.599578+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.692928+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.793717+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.891240+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
2013-08-14T11:10:07.988826+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.081153+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.176898+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.270800+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.380129+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.479684+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.576501+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.667801+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.762017+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.853310+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
2013-08-14T11:10:08.949795+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.046074+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.148684+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.254481+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.346373+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.443165+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.537368+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.629936+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.724946+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
2013-08-14T11:10:09.821164+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-08-14T11:10:09.915402+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:31,808 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Entry: AxisOperation::getInputAction
2013-08-14T11:10:10.007314+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:31,808 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Debug: AxisOperation::getInputAction - using soapAction
2013-08-14T11:10:10.098711+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:31,808 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Exit: AxisOperation::getInputAction urn:aDD_Set
2013-08-14T11:10:10.196483+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:31,808 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService - mapActionToOperation: Mapping Action to Operation: action: urn:aDD_Set; operation: org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation@63cea096named: {https://wsdlt.mailmanagement.ch}aDD_Set
2013-08-14T11:10:10.313217+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:31,809 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService - DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.callStackToString(JavaUtils.java:564)
2013-08-14T11:10:10.406680+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.mapActionToOperation(AxisService.java:821)
2013-08-14T11:10:10.503817+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.addOperation(AxisService.java:671)
2013-08-14T11:10:10.594496+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.populateAxisService(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:83)
2013-08-14T11:10:10.684708+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:155)
2013-08-14T11:10:10.775556+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:143)
2013-08-14T11:10:10.869511+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:193)
2013-08-14T11:10:10.960444+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.deindeal.utils.Connector2Navision.getStub(Connector2Navision.java:43)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.053732+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.deindeal.servlets.Product_Listener.sendAddProductJson2Nav(Product_Listener.java:55)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.145467+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.237472+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.331725+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.425849+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.526988+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.618648+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.710186+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.801199+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
2013-08-14T11:10:11.912056+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.004772+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.103079+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.204056+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.295579+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.401165+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.498186+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.590338+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.681735+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.781134+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.876145+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
2013-08-14T11:10:12.966751+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.058653+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.153885+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.246024+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.336630+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.427091+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.521203+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.611776+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.702643+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.796324+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.888971+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
2013-08-14T11:10:13.989727+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
2013-08-14T11:10:14.080646+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
2013-08-14T11:10:14.175454+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
2013-08-14T11:10:14.267640+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
2013-08-14T11:10:14.358530+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-08-14T11:10:14.460395+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:35,236 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Entry: AxisOperation::getInputAction
2013-08-14T11:10:14.551510+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:35,236 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Exit: AxisOperation::getInputAction null
2013-08-14T11:10:14.645889+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:35,236 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Entry: AxisOperation::setSoapAction, previous soapAction: null updated soapAction: urn:aDD_Product
2013-08-14T11:10:14.749829+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:35,236 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Exit: AxisOperation::setSoapAction
2013-08-14T11:10:14.841815+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:35,236 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService - mapActionToOperation: Mapping Action to Operation: action: aDD_Product; operation: org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation@12910b0bnamed: {https://wsdlt.mailmanagement.ch}aDD_Product
2013-08-14T11:10:14.939665+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:35,236 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService - DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.callStackToString(JavaUtils.java:564)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.031552+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.mapActionToOperation(AxisService.java:821)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.123221+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.addOperation(AxisService.java:667)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.218142+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.populateAxisService(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:95)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.310464+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:155)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.403189+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:143)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.496004+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:193)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.587066+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.deindeal.utils.Connector2Navision.getStub(Connector2Navision.java:43)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.677971+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.deindeal.servlets.Product_Listener.sendAddProductJson2Nav(Product_Listener.java:55)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.785332+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.876339+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2013-08-14T11:10:15.967781+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.061998+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.155372+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.246360+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.337972+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.432039+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.530836+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.621954+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.712591+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.805399+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.900001+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
2013-08-14T11:10:16.992340+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.085957+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.177752+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.272726+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.363042+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.456669+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.549878+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.640205+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.732889+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.823515+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
2013-08-14T11:10:17.916957+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.019158+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.112855+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.203207+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.297400+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.389069+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.484542+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.575953+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.666575+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.756752+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.847093+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
2013-08-14T11:10:18.939735+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-08-14T11:10:19.031729+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:38,669 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Entry: AxisOperation::getInputAction
2013-08-14T11:10:19.126387+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:42,417 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Debug: AxisOperation::getInputAction - using soapAction
2013-08-14T11:10:19.219583+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:42,417 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation - Exit: AxisOperation::getInputAction urn:aDD_Product
2013-08-14T11:10:19.310694+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:42,417 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService - mapActionToOperation: Mapping Action to Operation: action: urn:aDD_Product; operation: org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation@12910b0bnamed: {https://wsdlt.mailmanagement.ch}aDD_Product
2013-08-14T11:10:19.407251+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-08-14 11:09:42,418 [http-nio-58581-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService - DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.callStackToString(JavaUtils.java:564)
2013-08-14T11:10:19.498592+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.mapActionToOperation(AxisService.java:821)
2013-08-14T11:10:19.591805+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.addOperation(AxisService.java:671)
2013-08-14T11:10:19.683798+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.populateAxisService(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:95)
2013-08-14T11:10:19.775164+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:155)
2013-08-14T11:10:19.869090+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:143)
2013-08-14T11:10:19.963585+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.mailmanagement.wsdlt.SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.<init>(SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub.java:193)
2013-08-14T11:10:20.055228+00:00 app[web.1]:    DEBUG_FRAME = ch.deindeal.utils.Connector2Navision.getStub(Connector2Navision.java:43)
```

this is the method that gets stuck and seems to be running for a long time.

```
    //Generate client from the Stub.  
    SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub stub = null;

        logger.debug(">>>>> Creating connection."); 
        **stub = new SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub(URL);**
        logger.debug(">>>>> Connection created.");
```

and this is what it does inside: the bold letters indicate the method taking too long running.

```
public SQLEP_DeinDeal24Stub(org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext configurationContext,
            java.lang.String targetEndpoint, boolean useSeparateListener)
            throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
             //To populate AxisService
             logger.debug(">>>>> Populating axis service");
             **populateAxisService();**
             logger.debug(">>>>> Populating faults");
             populateFaults();     
        }

private void populateAxisService() throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {

     //creating the Service with a unique name
     _service = new org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService("SQLEP_DeinDeal24" + getUniqueSuffix());
     addAnonymousOperations();

        //creating the operations
        org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation __operation;

        _operations = new org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation[6];

                   __operation = new org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation();


            __operation.setName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("https://XXXXXX", "aDD_Purchase"));
        _service.addOperation(__operation);




            _operations[0]=__operation;


                   __operation = new org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation();


            __operation.setName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("https://XXXXXXX", "gET_Product_Stock"));
        _service.addOperation(__operation);




            _operations[1]=__operation;


                   __operation = new org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation();


            __operation.setName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("https://XXXXXXX", "aDD_Set"));
        _service.addOperation(__operation);




            _operations[2]=__operation;


                   __operation = new org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation();


            __operation.setName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("https://XXXXXXX", "aDD_Product"));
        _service.addOperation(__operation);




            _operations[3]=__operation;


                   __operation = new org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation();


            __operation.setName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("https://XXXXXXX", "gET_PurchaseResponse"));
        _service.addOperation(__operation);
```

Comment: Suggestion #1: paste the log here. Maybe also some relevant part of the code.

Comment: I think that it must be an internal problem of Heroku or something I dont get to understand. I have deployed the same app to Cloudbees and is running smoothly.